# Create an alert to email set User when Currency Exchange Rate is changed in NetSuite

Tags: sql, netsuite, currency, currency-exchange-rates

Currently in NetSuite if someone has at least the privilege EDIT on Currency, they can change the exchange rate provided by the rate provider.

The only search allowed is on the Currency Exchange Rate Historicals which is based on the date you created the save search and the remaining historicals. The User is the person who created it and not the System or User who changed the rate. There aren't many fields you can play with either. Needless to say, this way is convoluted on creating any connections for change notifications.

Since the Currency is a integration (add on) there isn't any customization allowed nor are the forms displayed.

I only found if we have Suitelet, that we would be able to call to the table in the database reference as Currency Rate; but we do not.

Is there anyway that I can create a field that can on that Currency Rate database?